# Trying to Pass sharedValue as initalParams get no default value error

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have a sharedValue in my navigator and I would like to pass it to each screen, so every screen has access to the sharedValue and can see when it changes.  However when I try to pass it as an initialParam in my TabNavigator it errors out saying "no default value".  I'm also open to a better way to pass an animated value to children, I tried using react context but that didn't work.

```
    const test = useSharedValue(12)
    
    <Tabs.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        initialParams={{test:test}}
     />
```

```
TypeError: No default value

This error is located at:
    in BottomTabBar (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by TabsNavigator)
    in TabsNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in CardSheet (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Card)
    in Card (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Screen)
    in MaybeFreeze (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by CardStack)
    in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
    in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
    in StackNavigator (created by MainNavigator)
    in MainNavigator (created by AppNavigator)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by AppNavigator)
    in AppNavigator (created by App)
    in PersistGate (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in DevAppContainer (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```